# Wordpress - Validating custom fields through backend

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

First off, I'm using advanced custom fields plugin, and I'm using a repeater. I have a custom post type that triggers when pressing "publish" when creating a new post, what it does, is that it adds a row to my repeater field.

Basiclly it takes the info from other fields and comes up with the proper information that the row created must have by making some calculations.

this is my function:

```
function investment_save($post_id)
{    
    $post = get_post();
    $poststat = get_post_status($post_id);
    $fecha = current_time(d-M-Y);
    $fecha2 = "Inversión ".$fecha;
    if($poststat == "publish" && !have_rows('datos_especificos'))
    {
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'investment_save' );

        $my_post = array(
        'ID'           => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $fecha2,
        );
        wp_update_post( $my_post );

        $fech = get_field('fecha_de_inicio_de_la_inversion');
        $sald = get_field('monto_de_la_inversion');
        $tasa = get_field('tasa_de_interes');
        $cap = get_field('uso_de_interes');


        $elsald0 = $tasa/12*0.01*$sald;
        $elsald=number_format($elsald0,2);

        if($cap=="pagar")
        {
            $cap2=$elsald;
            $cantr=0;
        }else{
            $cap2=0;
            $cantr=$elsald;
        }

        $sf = $sald+$cantr;

        $field_key = "datos_especificos";
        $value = get_field($field_key, $post_id);
        $value[] = array("fecha" => $fech, 
                         "saldo" => $sald,
                         "inversion_en_el_periodo" => "0",
                         "interes_causado_en_el_periodo" => $elsald,
                         "cantidad_pagada" => $cap2,
                         "cantidad_reinvertida" => $cantr,
                         "saldo_final" => $sf);
        update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'investment_save' );
```

This works properly, however, I have a new task in which everytime I press update, I must check if $cr+$cp equal $icelp in all rows, if they not, i must adjust the values from them, so this is the kind of code I'd like to use:

```
$sum = $cp + $cr;

    if($sum>$icelp)
    {
        $dif=$sum-$icelp;
        if($cp>=$cr)
        {
            $cp=$cp-$dif;
        }else
        {
            $cr=$cr-$dif;
        }
    }
    if($sum<$icelp)
    {
        $dif=$icelp-$sum;
        if($cp>=$cr)
        {
            $cr=$cr+$dif;
        }else
        {
            $cp=$cp+$dif;
        }
    }
```

Ive tried using an"else", also using an "if", but I just can't make it work. Please Someone help me I've been breaking my head for days

Comment: why don't you just replace the row with new updated row and not care about if it changed or not

Comment: You code works but you don't like it or I'm missing something?